# How to add small letter (sub) under a word in html and css bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How to add small letter (sub) under a word in html and css?
I am attaching the screenshot.
Want to write "Max 100, Min 1 just like the picture below.
my code is here:

```html
<input type="text" class="textarea" alt="" value="" style="color: #1c91df; height: 50px; width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; border-color: #1c91df; box-shadow: none; border-width: 1px;">

<input type="number" class="textarea" alt="height" value="10" style="color:#30a2ee;"/> Height <sub>Max 100</sub> <sub>Min 1</sub>
<input type="number" class="textarea1" alt="depth" value="10" style="color:#30a2ee;"/> Depth <sub>Max 100</sub> <sub>Min 1</sub>
```

[image]

Comment: Syntactically those are not sub elements.

Comment: Please put your code into a runnable snippet (ie including bootstrap) as it makes it much easier to give a suitable complete answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please check my answer.  : )  https://stackoverflow.com/a/74308990/14912225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for. : )
I am attaching a screenshot of it.
[image]

Here's the code.

```html
<div class="demention">
  <input type="number" class="textarea" alt="height" value="10" style="color:#30a2ee;"/>
  <p class="big_text">Height</p>
  
  <input type="number" class="textarea" alt="depth" value="100" style="color:#30a2ee;"/>
  <p class="big_text">Depth</p>
</div>

<style>
  .demention {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 50px;
  }
  .demention .textarea {
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #30a2ee;
  }
  .demention .big_text {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 30px;
    color: #30a2ee;
  }
  p.big_text:before {
    content: "Max. 100";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  p.big_text:after {
    content: "Min. 1";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 40px;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: If you think this resolved your issue, are you able to accept this answer? Thanks. : )

Answer (score 1):

```
sub {
    text-transform: lowercase; 
}
```

There are 5 different values you can use:

```
**lowercase**: makes all of the letters in the selected text lowercase
**uppercase**: makes all of the letters in the selected text uppercase or ALL CAPS
**capitalize**: capitalizes the first letter of each word in the selected text
none: leaves the text's case and capitalization exactly as it was entered
**inherit**: gives the text the case and capitalization of its parent
**full-width**: This is a keyword forcing the writing of a character (mainly ideograms and Latin scripts) inside a square.
```

Comment: The picture shown in the question does not have all of that test as lowercase, nor as a subscript.

Answer (score 1):

There are million of ways to do that. For example you can use flex:

```
<div class="mygroup">
  <input type="number" class="textarea" alt="height" value="10" style="color:#30a2ee;"/>
  <div class="mystyle">
    <span>Height</span>
    <sub>Max 100</sub> 
    <sub>Min 1</sub>
  </div>
  
  <input type="number" class="textarea1" alt="width" value="10" style="color:#30a2ee;"/>
  <div class="mystyle">
    <span>Width</span>
    <sub>Max 100</sub>
    <sub>Min 1</sub>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
.mygroup {
  display: flex;
}
.mystyle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this custom css inside your css file and check again.

```
sub {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Comment: The picture shown in the question does not have all of that test as lowercase, nor as a subscript.